# Hive: Difference between CREATE FUNCTION and CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION in Hive UDF

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql, hive-udf

I am new to the hive and I am working on a project where I need to create a few UDFs for data wrangling. During my research, I came across two syntaxes for creating UDF from added jars

```
CREATE FUNCTION country AS 'com.hiveudf.employeereview.Country';

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION country AS 'com.hiveudf.employeereview.Country';
```

I am not able to find any difference in the above two ways. Can someone explain it to me or guide me to right material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between create function and create tmp function is this:
In Hive 0.13 or later, functions can be registered to the metastore, so they can be referenced in a query without having to create a temporary function each session.

If we use CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION , we will have to recreate the function every-time we start a new session.

Reference: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/ReloadFunction

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` creates a new function which you can use in Hive queries as long as the session lasts . This is faster as we don't need to register the functions to the megastore.
Whereas `CREATE FUNCTION` acts more permanently. These functions can be registered to the metastore, so they can be referenced in a query without having to create a temporary function each session.

`When to use`:
The intermediate functions can be created using `TEMPORARY` which aims to just compute and can be later on used by any permanent functions.
[Reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/ReloadFunction)

Comment: Thanks. It adds a lot more sense now.